# WP WooCommerce doesn't change variation on iOS Chrome

Tags: jquery, ios, wordpress, google-chrome, woocommerce

I'm working on woocommerce project - www.ekomob.lt

I ran into a bug with iOS Chrome. Or at least I've noticed it on iOS Chrome. When you are switching between variations - price doesn't change. In fact, nothing really changes.

Example product: http://ekomob.lt/product/sony-xperia-z5-premium/

"Auksinis" variation has 619 euro pricetag
Other two has 629 euro pricetag.

Comment: Test with other plugins disabled and with a default theme. If the problem is still reproducible then you should report the bug to Woothemes.

Comment: Thank you, apparently some weird part of js code was breaking and caused all of the js to break in iOS devices, so removing it solved the problem.

Comment: Cool. It always helps to do this to reduce the number of "moving parts" and isolate the problem.